# How to add user and a group in Docker Container running Macosx

Tags: linux, docker, macos, docker-compose, sh

I have a Docker container running "FROM arm64v8/oraclelinux:8" , I am running this on a Mac m1 mini using tightvnc.

I want to add a user called "suiteuser" (uid 42065) and in a group called "cvsgroup" (gid 513), inside my docker container, So that when I run the container it starts under my user directly.

Here is my entire Dockerfile-

```
FROM arm64v8/oraclelinux:8

# Setup basic environment stuff
ENV container docker
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV TZ EST
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


# Base image stuff
#RUN yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel vim yum-utils sssd sssd-tools krb5-libs krb5-workstation.x86_64

# CCSMP dependent
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN yum install -y openssl-libs-1.1.1g-15.el8_3.aarch64
RUN yum install -y krb5-workstation krb5-libs krb5-devel
RUN yum install -y glibc-devel glibc-common
RUN yum install -y make gcc java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tar perl maven svn openssl-devel gcc
RUN yum install -y gdb
RUN yum install -y openldap* openldap-clients nss-pam-ldapd
RUN yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel vim yum-utils sssd sssd-tools

# Minor changes to image to get ccsmp to build
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm
RUN cp /usr/include/linux/stddef.h /usr/include/stddef.h

# Install ant 1.10.12
RUN wget https://mirror.its.dal.ca/apache//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.10.12-bin.zip
RUN unzip apache-ant-1.10.12-bin.zip && mv apache-ant-1.10.12/ /opt/ant


ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
ENV ANT_HOME="/usr/bin/ant"
ENV PATH="/usr/bin/ant:$PATH"


CMD /bin/bash
```

could anyone please suggest any ideas on how to do this.

**Note 1.** I know its not advisable to do this directly in the container as, every time you want to make any changes you would have to rebuild it, but this time i want to do this.

Comment: sooooo `RUN adduser suiteuser && addgroup cvsgroup`.

Comment: both adduser and addgroup throws error during build saying unknown command, I believe its because its running arm64v8/oraclelinux:8 and its running on mac m1 mini server.

Answer (score 0):

To create the group:

```
RUN groupadd -g 513 cvsgroup
```

To create the user, as a member of that group:

```
RUN useradd -G cvsgroup -m -u 42065 suiteuser
```

And toward the end of Dockerfile, you can set the user:

```
USER suiteuser
```

There may be more to do here, though, depending on your application. For example, you may need to chown some of the contents to be owned by `suiteuser`.